# Sorting a list from Excel from highest to lowest

Tags: python, excel, sorting

I need to do sort three students' scores from an existing Excel file, find their maximum, then output those scores from highest to lowest in a new Excel file.

I understand how to read from the file and find the maximum. This is my code so far:

```
import csv
import operator
file_reader=open("scoreresults.csv","r")
csv_r=csv.reader(file_reader,delimiter=",")
file_writer =open( "score results output.csv","w", newline="")
csv_w=csv.writer(file_writer)
newdata=[]
for row in csv_r:
    forename,deposit1,deposit2,deposit3=row
    newdata.append(forename)
    newdata.append(deposit1)
    newdata.append(deposit2)
    newdata.append(deposit3)

    file=[forename,deposit1,deposit2,deposit3]
    maximumn=max(file)
    file1=[forename,maximumn]
    file1.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    csv_w.writerow([file1])
file_reader.close()
file_writer.close()
```

I didn't add the bit where I tried to sort it as I completely fail there. When I tried to use `itemgetter` I could only print, not save to a file and it sorted from lowest to highest.

An example of how it should look is:

```
name score                                       name score
James 2                     should turn into     sam  10   
sam   10                                         jane  9
dan    5                                         dan   5
lee    4                                         lee   4
jane   9                                         james 2
```

Comment: Shouldn't you. 1) read all input in a loop, 2) call your sort routine 3) write out your sorted list in another loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

with  open("scoreresults.csv","r") as r, open( "score_results_output.csv","w", newline="") as f:
    csv_w = csv.writer(f)
    csv_r = csv.reader(r)
    csv_w.writerows(sorted((((name, max(scores,key=int)) 
                    for name,*scores in csv_r)), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

Write the header first with  `csv_w.writerow(next(csv_r))` then sorted the rows getting the max of the scores for each user with `max(scores,key=int))`, pass the key `key=itemgetter(1)` to sort the elements by the second element which is the max score for each use with `reverse=True` to sort from highest to lowest.

Input:

```
name,score
sam,10,12,13
dan,5,23,2
lee,4,23,5
jane,9,2,10
```

Output:

```
name,score
dan,23
lee,23
sam,13
jane,10
```

Based on `forename,deposit1,deposit2,deposit3=row` I presume you have a name and three scores per row

You are making life much harder than it need be in your own code, the reason your sort would never work is you are comparing strings not ints, you would need to cast to int:

```
file1.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```